# C# FTPWebRequest for reading multiple files

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I want to get content​ for each file situated on FTP. I'm going to develop it for  with FTPWebRequet in C# Windows Application. But I'm searching for best and correct way for doing it.

For example I am looking for a file as

```
tmpReq = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://" + Settings.Default.IP + "/953077/Inserted/XMLComp" + CryptoHelper.Decrypt(Settings.Default.RegCode) + ".xml");
```

but how can I do it for multiple files

in loop i can create FtpWebRequest and change the fileName XMLComp95202. But i think it's not the best way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't know the name of the files you want on the FTP server- correct? If not you'll have to get a directory of files and loop over the results. Check out WebRequestMethods.FTP."methods"

Comment: no i know the  names of file. for sample XMLComp" + CryptoHelper.Decrypt(Settings.Default.RegCode) + ".xml is equal to  XMLComp952025.xml or XMLComp952026.xml

Comment: in loop i can create FtpWebRequest and change the fileName  XMLComp95202<i(it become from loop)>. But i think it's not the bes way to do it with this way

Comment: Ah - well if you are using MS FTP utility I don't think they enhanced the basic protocol too much - You can check out other implementations (such as Dart) that provide multi file gets

Answer (score 0):

You must use:

`request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;`

You need to connect with the main path first, I mean, if the files are in ftp://.../files/, you must get the response first of this pathm based on Directory request, then you recive a large string of all files content in this folder.

Using a recursive method, for each line, you must to do a request again.